# Can I get Dishonored to stop asking for admin access whenever I run it?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, dishonored

Every time I run Dishonored under Steam I get a pop up asking me for my Administrator password (I run as a normal user account, I imagine a UAC prompt would come up if I was running as Admin). I think this is due to the Steam first-time setup being run every time.

In response to comments:

- No other Steam game has this issue, only Dishonored
- It's installed on a mechanical HDD, while Steam is on an SSD
- I am running a Steam Beta which allows selecting a different install directory
- My Windows user account is not an admin (hence the UAC privileges popup appearing)

Is there any way to correct this issue?

Comment: Shows how long it has been since I last played.  Just started playing again yesterday.  It installed an update, played, played today then BAM!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***You will need administrator rights to apply this fix***

According to a Steam [forums post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140409153525/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=33074483&postcount=9):

You should launch `regedit` (runnable via <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\Steam\Apps\205100`, right mouseclick on the right pane and click "new DWORD" (32-bit), name it "PhysXRedist" and give it a value of 1.

Restart the game and it shouldn't bug you anymore.

---

If you don't feel comfortable going into the registry yourself, run one of these commands instead depending on your version of Windows:

32-bit Windows:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Valve\Steam\Apps\205100 /v PhysXRedist /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

64-bit Windows:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\Steam\Apps\205100 /v PhysXRedist /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: UAC will always point you to the "Admin or else" dialog.